# Node.js: req.object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
// MERGE OBJECT = unsent columns are kept from old objects !
function merge_options(obj1, obj2) {
  const obj3 = {};
  for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
  for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
  return obj3;
}
async function parseDBrequestMergeUniqueOne(req, dbName, keyName) {
  if (req.object.isNew()) {
    logger.info('object new');

    const query = new Parse.Query(dbName);
    query.equalTo(keyName, req.object(keyName));
    const objectOld = await query.first({ useMasterKey: true });
logger.info('object new');

    if (!req.object.get(keyName)) {
      throw new `Table: ${dbName} must have key ${keyName}.`;
    } else if (objectOld) {
      // update
      const oldo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectOld));
      const newo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.object));
      const merge2 = merge_options(oldo, newo);
      req.object.destroy({ useMasterKey: true }); // delete old object - we will replace it with a new one
      for (const attrname in merge2) {
        objectOld.set(attrname, merge2[attrname]);
      }
      objectOld.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
     throw new Error("I'm Evil")
    }
  }
}


// / use generic function to class test, unique column = uniqKey
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Test1',  (request) => {
     return parseDBrequestMergeUniqueOne(request, 'Test1', 'title');
});
```

I get an error in the console :

```
2020-06-26T21:27:17.668Z - req.object is not a function
2020-06-26T21:27:17.661Z - beforeSave failed for Test1 for user YCjqkqOGO4:
Input: {"title":"test1","testPF":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Test2","objectId":"AnxhevVa8s"},"title2":"8","title3":"1","testRL":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Test2","objectId":"gOcJGkttpk"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Test2","objectId":"AnxhevVa8s"}]}}
Error: {"message":"request.object is not a function","code":141}
2020-06-26T21:27:17.651Z - object new
```

Why?

Comment: `query.equalTo(keyName, req.object(keyName));` what should this do?

Comment: I bet that `if (req.object.isNew())` causing an error. Are you sure that `request` has `object` property?

Comment: This cloud code Parse Server.

req.object - new PFObject (created on client, but not recorded in the db)

>> query.equalTo(keyName, req.object(keyName));

Request to get data from the database (return PFObject or null)
Checking if there is an entry in the column (KeyName) with the value (req.object(keyName))

Comment: >> Are you sure that request has object property? 100% yes

Comment: `req.object - new PFObject` that very heavily suggests that `req.object` is *not* a function, so trying to execute it as one doesn't make sense. Again, what should `query.equalTo(keyName, req.object(keyName));` considering that *you cannot execute objects*?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcgjOuI4rb4
if remove "return" then the code is executed but ignored throw new Error("I'm Evil")


Sorry my English

Comment: If the pfobject exists, then it needs to be updated current entry . If there is no pfobject, then create a new entry. Without "return": the old pfobject is updated and  created new record (entry)
 With "return": req.object is not a function

Comment: `query.equalTo(keyName, req.object[keyName]);` <- sure you dont mean this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // MERGE OBJECT = unsent columns are kept from old objects !
function merge_options(obj1, obj2) {
  const obj3 = {};
  for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
  for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
  return obj3;
}
async function parseDBrequestMergeUniqueOne(req, dbName, keyName) {
  if (req.object.isNew()) {
    logger.info('object new'+req.id);
    const query = new Parse.Query(dbName);
    query.equalTo(keyName, req.object.get(keyName));
    const objectOld = await query.first({ useMasterKey: true });

    if (!req.object.get(keyName)) {
      throw `Table: ${dbName} must have key ${keyName}.`;
    } else if (objectOld) {
      // update
      const oldo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectOld));
      const newo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.object));
      const merge2 = merge_options(oldo, newo);
      await req.object.destroy({ useMasterKey: true }); // delete old object - we will replace it with a new one
      for (const attrname in merge2) {
        objectOld.set(attrname, merge2[attrname]);
      }
      await objectOld.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
     throw "I'm Evil"
    }
  }
}


// / use generic function to class test, unique column = uniqKey
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Test1', async (requ) => {
    await parseDBrequestMergeUniqueOne(requ, 'Test1', 'title');
});
```

It's work